# position: sticky not working in desktop but OK in mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with this error.
I add position:sticky; to a div and it is not working when I am on desktop mode (max-width: 760px) but it works when I am in mobile mode.

Here is my code

```css
/* TOOL BAR */

.tool-bar {
  /* Fixed size for the tool bar */
  width: 100px;
  /* To add a space between the header and the tool bar */
  margin: 30px 0;
  /* To have a nice column distribution centered */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* Keep the tool bar on screen when scrolling */
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /* Tool bar */
  .tool-bar {
    /* Take all the space instead of 100px */
    width: 100%;
    /* Stick the tool bar on the header to win space */
    margin: 0;
    /* Keep the bar tool visible when scrolling */
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-bar">
  <!-- TOOLS -->
  <div class="tools">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="pictures/grids.png" alt="Grid" id="grid"></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/pen.png" alt="Pen" id="pen"></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/fill.png" alt="Fill" id="fill"></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/dropper.png" alt="Dropper" id="dropper"></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/eraser.png" alt="Eraser" id="eraser"></li>
      <li><input type="color" id="color-picker" class="color-picker-style"></li>
      <li><img src="pictures/reset.png" alt="Reset" id="reset"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

In desktop mode, it behaves as a position: relative.

I have already checked, no overflow, no height: 100%...

If you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure your browser supports sticky.
https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky.
Secondly, the sticky element only sticks inside its parent, if the parent only has a height equal to the child, you will not see any effect.

Edit: more on position sticky can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I checked both of your proposition and it is not that =/

Comment: Sure, sorry it is a big one working usually with a bit of JavaScript.
Hope it will be ok
https://jsfiddle.net/maevanapcontact/4u7450rc/

Comment: Figured it out, the sticky position should in this case be applied to the class tools, not tool-bar. toolbar is a flex child and therefor takes up height equal to its sibling. [check out my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u7450rc/1/).

Comment: Great! That works! Thanks a lot! I still keep in on tool-bar in mobile state else it is not working. I can't figure out why =/ Thanks!